# apache2.conf vs mpm_prefork.conf priority

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running Apache 2.4.18 with Ubuntu 16. I have `mpm_prefork` module installed but I noticed there is two config directives for it; the settings being held in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf` and the standard if module block in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

With a clean install both of those config files contain settings–roughly the same values. The problem I'm wondering about is which files options take precedence, or should they even both have settings for the `mpm_prefork` module? If not, which one should the settings be set in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in `mods-available` is not taken into account by Apache... except if you have a symlink to some file there from `mods-enabled`.

So, `apache2.conf` content is what counts, and then is loaded what is in `mods-enabled`. This is the standard setup in multiple distributions, a sysadmin could decide to organize things differently if he wishes.

Comment: So essentially the file in `mods-available` is just the template settings?

Comment: Like the default values you can use if you symlink from `mods-enables` but you are free to use other configuration items.